# Division and multiplication – reordering operands and operations

Tags: arithmetic

Precedence with division and multiplication matters. For example:

$$
(80 \div 10) \times 5 = 40\\
80 \div (10 \times 5) = \frac{8}{5}
$$

More generally, I might write:

$$
(A \div B) \times C \neq A \div (B \times C)
$$

(Although sometimes that equation holds.) But it does seem like I can move around operands and their operations, for example:

$$
5600 \div 8 = (56 \times 100) \div 8 = (56 \div 8) \times 100 = 7 \times 100 = 700
$$

Which makes me wonder:

$$
(A \div B) \times C = (A \times C) \div B
$$

Why does one seem to work and the other doesn't? I'd really appreciate a small visual demonstration if possible.

Comment: The first fails because you are changing what you divide by.  Dividing by B is not the same as dividing by BxC.  In the second you are dividing by B in both.  The difference is that in one you are dividing by B before multiplying the result by C, and the second you are dividing by B after multiplying by C.  It doesn't actually matter what order you multiply and divide by but it does matter *what* you multiply by.  The parenthesis aren't really about order as grouping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Fact 1:** Division by $b$ is the same as multiplication by $\frac 1b$: $a\div b = a\times \frac 1b$.

**Fact 2:** You can change the order of multiplication: $a\times b = b\times a$.

**Fact 3:** You can move the parentheses around however you like if all of your operations are multiplication: $((a\times b)\times c)\times d = a\times ((b\times c)\times d) = \cdots$.

**So:** $$\begin{align}(A \div B) \times C &= \left(A\times \frac 1B\right) \times C \\ &= A\times \left(\frac 1B \times C\right) \\ &= A\times \left(C\times \frac 1B\right) \\ &= (A\times C) \times \frac 1B \\ &= (A \times C) \div B\end{align}$$

---

To see why $(A \div B) \times C \neq A \div (B \times C)$ we use the same properties as above and compare the left (LHS) and right hand sides (RHS).

LHS: $$(A \div B) \times C = \left(A\times \frac 1B\right)\times C = A\times \left(\frac 1B\times C\right)$$

RHS: $$A \div (B \times C) = A \times \left(\frac{1}{B\times C}\right)$$

These are clearly different.

Comment: I see. So when you change the order of operations without moving the operands, you're potentially changing intermediate values. For example, $(80 \times \frac{1}{10}) \times 5 \neq 80 \times \frac{1}{10 \times 50}$.

Comment: Yep.$\ \ \ \ \ $

Comment: Can you do similar tricks with division? What would the rule be to cover all operands (+, -, *, /)? As a guess, I'd say something like "+ and - can be reordered within their own group (parens). * can be reordered within a group of * and /. / can be converted to 1/x and then reordered within a group of * and /. / cannot be reordered." I'm not sure that's right, but please correct where necessary.